# Запустить exce с использованием LibreOffice в PHP под Docker

Tags: php, linux, docker, office

Есть проект в Docker и PHP, одна из целей - конвертация бинарного excel в простой, то есть изменение формата с `xlsb` на `xlsx`.

```
$output = [];
$return_var = 0;
$sh = exec('soffice --headless --convert-to xlsx file.xlsb --outdir outDir',
    $output,
    $return_var);

var_dump($sh, $output, $return_var);
```

Все необходимые пакеты установлены, но у `soffice` нет прав на запись нового файла из под `PHP` из-за чего он завершает работу с кодом `77`.

Если пробовать ввести `soffice --headless --convert-to xlsx file.xlsb --outdir outDir` в консоль контейнера Docker, то всё работает. Так же всё работает на сервере без Docker (но это не вариант).
Какие есть пути решения и как я в Docker могу запустить `soffice`?

Comment: Ну значит просто выдайте для PHP права на запись в указанный каталог, наверное?

Comment: Нет, мимо. Права у PHP на запись есть, создается директория через mkdir или простой файл из `exce`. Директории принадлежат www-data и права 777. В Dockerfile так же даю права `RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/`, так же пробовал запускать от измени `www-data` (`USER www-data`), но это не помогло.

Comment: Покажите какой-нибудь минимальный воспроизводимый докерфайл? Попробую запустить у себя

Comment: Залил на Yandex Disk: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/-cAy-xpEleGvmg

Comment: А надо бы в текст вопроса без лишней шелухи

Comment: Из-за того, что вы воткнули `USER www-data` в самое начало `PHP/Dockerfile`, образ контейнера вообще не может собраться, потому что `apt-get install` не имеет прав на запись. А то, что вы не заметили эту ошибку, намекает на то, что вы, возможно, банально забываете пересобрать образ. Внимательно перепроверьте, как вы работаете с докером

Comment: Когда я переместил эту строку в конец докерфайла, запустил контейнер и обратился к php-скрипту — я получил вывод `string(115) "convert /var/www/application/file.xlsb -> /var/www/application/outDir/file.xlsx using filter : Calc Office Open XML" array(1) { [0]=> string(115) "convert /var/www/application/file.xlsb -> /var/www/application/outDir/file.xlsx using filter : Calc Office Open XML" } int(0) `

Comment: Соответственно, файл `outDir/file.xlsx` успешно появился, никаких ошибок нет, всё работает

Comment: Так же переместил строку в конце и всё заработало, разместил в начале её по ошибке для примера и не перепроверил, из-за чего Dockerfile в таком виде и отправил. Вы оказались правы, `USER www-data` действительно исправил проблему (хотя до этого он был в конце файла, не знаю какая другая проблема мешала конвертации, так как ошибок было множество). Спасибо за помощь :)